# Ouvindo stdout do console Linux com python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Estou tentando fazer um script em python com o qual preciso ouvir o **stdout** do console linux. O script é para testar taxa de erro de transmissão serial para gravação de imagem de um SO em uma placa colibri iMX, pois, existem algumas inconsistências na gravação por serial TX/RX, principalmente de timeout.

O script funciona perfeitamente, porém, não encontrei nenhuma forma de ouvir o **stdout** do console sem precisar executar um arquivo/script ou processo utilizando o módulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) do python com a função `Popen()`.
O código que captura o stdout de um arquivo está da seguinte forma, sendo o `cmd` a saída de um `echo` ou `script/arquivo` :

```
import subprocess
import sys


def run(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            )
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

    return proc.returncode, stdout, stderr


code, out, err = run([sys.executable, 'run.py'])

print("out: '{}'".format(out))
print("err: '{}'".format(err))
print("exit: {}".format(code))
```

O que preciso fazer é escutar o **stdout** do console em tempo de execução, sem ter que executar algo antes - script/arquivo - para gerar uma saída no stdout. Porém, não sei se é possível fazer isso.

Valeu!

Comment: Me parece uma confusão de conceitos, se entendi bem. Cada processo tem um stdin, stderr e um stdout, não tem sentido pensar em ouvir um stdout sem processo. Assim como não tem "um console do linux" e sim cada console aberto é gerenciado por um processo independente (seja pelo getty ou quem for no sistema específico). Seria o caso do Py abrir o processo da gravação, pra poder acompanhar (novamente, se é que entendi a idéia, ficou meio confuso o post, acho). Alternativamente seu script poderia abrir um pipe e em outro console você redirecionar o stdout pra esse pipe, mas acho que complica à toa.

Comment: lembrando ainda que você tem o `tee` na linha de comando se precisar dividir uma saída para mais de um destino